# Content doesn't show up in the dashboard body if the sidebar menu is dynamically created

Tags: dynamic, menu, shiny, sidebar, dashboard

I noticed if the sidebar menu is created dynamically by the server code, the content doesn't show up when the app loads until after a tab is clicked.

In the example, I used the sample code from the shiny dashboard get started page. The app runs as expected. However, as you can see, I change the sidebar menu to be dynamically created, a blank page shows up when app loads. I have to click on the first tab at the side bar to bring up the page. Is there a way to display a default page, namely the dashboard tab page?  Please note I entered an issue on shiny dashboard github page.  Thanks much for your help.

```
`## app.R ##
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
## Sidebar content
# dashboardSidebar(
# sidebarMenu(
# menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
# menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
# )
# ),

dashboardSidebar(width=150, sidebarMenuOutput("sideMenu")
),

dashboardBody(

tabItems(
  # First tab content
  tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
          fluidRow(
            box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),

            box(
              title = "Controls",
              sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
            )
          )
  ),

  # Second tab content
  tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
          h2("Widgets tab content")
  )
)
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

output$sideMenu <- renderMenu({
sidebarMenu(
menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
)
})

set.seed(122)
histdata <- rnorm(500)

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
hist(data)
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)`
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set one of your tabs to be active.

For example:

```
# First tab content
  tabItem(tabName = "dashboard", class = "active",
           fluidRow(
            box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),

            box(
              title = "Controls",
              sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
            )
          )
     ),
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks much.